# In VS Code, is there a way to programmatically set the filenamePatterns of a language in package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We're able to set context variables in typescript for an extension through the call to `vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', VarName, VarValue)` which are usable in "when" clauses for commands in the package.json. What I'm trying to do is dynamically set the filenamePatterns of a language entry.

```json
"languages": [
      {
        "id": "MyLanguage",
        "aliases": ["MyLanguage", "mylanguage"],
        "filenamePatterns": [ /* trying to set this dynamically */ ]
      }
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically, either through setting a context variable or a way to access the language in typescript to set these? I need to pull some values from a config file and create the glob pattern based upon those entries which I don't have ahead of time.